# How do I resolve this promise after a for-loop of asynchronous code finishes?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

Can't seem to figure out how to make this work without the setTimeout.
I want to console log my map only after the asynchronous PostgreSQL stuff is finished and the map contains all the key/value pairs it should.

```
const map = new Map();
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM trips WHERE destination = $1 AND begin_time >= $2 AND begin_time < $3 ORDER BY begin_time`, ['BROWNSVILLE ROCKAWAY AV', '2018-07-18 00:00-04:00', '2018-07-19 00:00-04:00'])
.then(res => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { rows } = res;
        resolve(rows);
    });
})
.then(res1 => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res1.length; i++) {
            if (res1[i + 1]) {
                pool.query(`SELECT * FROM get_hwtable($1, $2)`, [res1[i].trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id]).then(res => {
                    const { rows: hwRows } = res;
                    map.set([res1[i].trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id], hwRows);
                }).catch(e => console.log('20', e));
            }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(map);
        }, 8000);
    });
})
.catch(e => console.log('25', e))
.finally(function () {
    console.log(map);
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all` on an array of promises returned by `pool.query`

Comment: `.then(res => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const { rows } = res;
        resolve(rows);
    });
})` no need for that whole code block!!

Comment: you could probably rewrite your code as https://pastebin.com/hNyT36UG

Comment: Awesome! That works! As for that first then code block; it needs to be there in order to pull out the rows array from the response I get back from the database, as that is the data I care about.

Comment: oh, yeah, misread the code ... it can just be `.then(({rows}) => rows)` - no need to construct a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Promise.all` on an array of promises returned by `pool.query`

```
const map = new Map();
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM trips WHERE destination = $1 AND begin_time >= $2 AND begin_time < $3 ORDER BY begin_time`, ['BROWNSVILLE ROCKAWAY AV', '2018-07-18 00:00-04:00', '2018-07-19 00:00-04:00'])
.then(({rows}) => rows)
.then(res1 => Promise.all(res1.map((r, i) => {
    if (res1[i + 1]) {
        return pool.query(`SELECT * FROM get_hwtable($1, $2)`, [r.trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id])
        .then(res => {
            const { rows: hwRows } = res;
            map.set([res1[i].trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id], hwRows);
        }).catch(e => console.log('20', e))
    }                                 
})))
.catch(e => console.log('25', e))
.finally(function () {
    console.log(map);
});
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you could use object destructuring like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. there are unnecessary constructs in your code. In first `then( res => {..} )`,
   there is no need to return a `Promise`. You can do

```

```
pool.query().then(res => {
    const {rows} = res;
    return rows;
}.then ....
```

```

2. If you are already using `async` you should use `await` and use this for the whole code block. Could write a promisified timeout function too.

```

```
///returns a promise that resolves after `duration`
function timeoutPromise(duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, duration)
  })
}

async function doSomething() {
  const res = await pool.query()
  const {rows} = res;
  for (...) {
    let hwRows = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM get_hwtable($1, $2)`, [res1[i].trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id]);
    map...
  }
  await timeoutPromise(5000)
}

doSomething()
```

```

3. Of course the above might make the user wait too long because the asynchronous operations (`let hwRows = await pool.query()`) will be executed one after another. use `Array.map` to return an array of `Promise` and then use `Promise.all([Promise])` to get the values.

```

```
async function doSomething() {
  const res = await pool.query()
  const {rows} = res;
  let hwRowsPromises = rows.map((row) => {
    // ...
    // return the promise
    return pool.query(`SELECT * FROM get_hwtable($1, $2)`, [res1[i].trip_id, res1[i + 1].trip_id])
  })
  let hwRowsResults = Promise.all(hwRowsPromises)
  await timeoutPromise(5000)
}
```

```
4. `Promise.all` resolves the values resolved by promises in an array, so you can use convenience like [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap) to flatten the array.

```

```
_.flatten([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]);
// => [1, 2, [3, [4]], 5]
```

```

## References

- [Promise.all(iterable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)